# HTML5 Audio - stop current play when another sound is started

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am using this method to play audio files when you click on an image:

http://jsfiddle.net/v97Kq/3/

```
function imageSwitch(_imgID, _imgStart, _imgStop, _soundFileMp3, _soundFileOgg) {
    this.imgID = _imgID;
    this.imgStart = _imgStart;
    this.imgStop = _imgStop;
    this.song = new Audio();
    if (this.song.canPlayType("audio/mpeg"))
        this.song.src = _soundFileMp3;
    else 
        this.song.src = _soundFileOgg;
    this.song.loop = true;

    this.pos = 0;
    this.e;

    this.change = function () {
        if (this.pos == 0) {
            this.pos = 1;
            document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStop;
            this.song.play();
        } else {
            this.pos = 0;
            document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStart;
            this.song.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

It works good! - but how can I get it to stop playing the currently playing sound when another link is clicked and another sound begins?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to my issue above, works perfectly.
which I eventually found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362317/how-to-stop-one-audio-player-from-playing-when-i-click-another-javascript):

```
<script>
var currentPlayer;
function EvalSound(soundobj) {

 var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
 if(currentPlayer  && currentPlayer != thissound) {
  currentPlayer.pause(); 
 }
 if (thissound.paused)
        thissound.play();
    else
    thissound.pause();
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
     currentPlayer = thissound;
}
</script>
```