# JavaScript start new track when a different track is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have this function:

```
function audioPlayer(band, album, track) {
    var audio = new Audio; //Class\
    audio.src = 'music/' + band + '/' + album + '/' + track + '.mp3';
    audio.play();
}
```

It will play the song that is clicked. But when another song is clicked I'll hear both songs play.

I have tried multiple suggestions already but none of them seem to work for me.
I have tried:

- [How to stop one audio player from playing when I click another - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362317/how-to-stop-one-audio-player-from-playing-when-i-click-another-javascript)
- [HTML5 Audio stop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834520/html5-audio-stop-function)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589489(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.binarytides.com/stop-function-html5-audio-element/

I don't use the html5 `<audio>` tag only JavaScript / jQuery.

Is there a way to make the first song stop and than just play the other?

If you need more information please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to keep track of a shared `audio` variable. When you call `audioPlayer(,,)`, you'll stop that variable, set the src, and then play it. Something to that effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your `audio` variable global, this will work:

```
var audio = new Audio;

function audioPlayer(band, album, track) {
    audio.src = 'music/' + band + '/' + album + '/' + track + '.mp3';
    audio.play();
}
```